# How to change the root folder permission in linux centos

Tags: linux, centos, root

I have currently this permission in my / folder.

`drwxr-xr-x`. I have seen that anyone can open that folder.

How can remove the executable permission from that so that other permission remain same 
Also is any other main folder in / where i need to remove public executable permission

Comment: Why is it a problem for the root directory to be readable? There's normally just other directories there anyways.

Comment: so u mean , it is ok for other users to see the contents of root folder. i was thinking if i did that by mistake

Comment: it's perfectly fine. Users' home directories should be blocked off in this way, certain system config folders as well... but in general most directories are fully readable/listable.

Comment: thanks mark , i will leave as it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By removing executable permission in `/` you'll make anything under it inaccessible. You can do it with `chmod -x /` but it's **highly inadvisable**.

For most practical purposes this will make everything inaccessible to regular users. Even worse, this will likely prevent ssh connections to the box so even with root you'll need physical access to a tty.

Comment: or anyway to prevent some users to see the directories in root folder

Answer (score 2):

```
chmod a-x /
```

will remove/subtract the e`x`ecute permission for all (`'a'`) from folder `/` -- is there a particular reason for wanting to do this?

See the "symbolic Mode" on this [chmod man page](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) for more information.

Comment: Good luck recovering the system after this is done... especially if you don't know what was done.

Comment: @MarcB I'm not saying that this is a good idea, just answering OPs query.

Answer (score 1):

To change all the folders & sub-folders (directories) permission to 755 inside the directory `/path/to/directory`, use the below command.

```
find /path/to/directory -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

To change all the file permissions to 644 inside the directory `/path/to/directory`

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

### For more reading: chmod - Understanding Folder & File Permissions

```
0: no permission,
1: execute
2: write
3: write and execute
4: read
5: read and execute
6: read and write
7: read, write, and execute
```

#### Folder Permissions:

- Read: Be Able To Read Folder Contents,
- Write: Edit folders data. delete or create new files/folders inside it and etc,
- Execute: Able to run\execute the Folder Contents.

#### Similarly, File Permissions:

- Read: if it's text file like index.html or index.php then user\browser be able to read it.
- Write: ability to change its data.
- Execute: if it's script like index.php run it to get resultant data from it.